# How to automatically type in a Windows password on the login screen?

Tags: python, windows, authentication

I've been making a facial recognition login system for my Windows 10 PC with Python. The idea is that it will automatically type in my password and log me in when the camera sees me. Not much more efficient than just entering a PIN or disabling the password, I know, but it's a fun project that I've been working on.

Currently, this all works until I get to typing the password. The first key, spacebar, works and opens the login text box. However, the rest of the inputs aren't entered, despite the program correctly sending the commands.

So far, I have tried using the *keyboard*, *pyKey*, *pyautogui*, and *pyInput* modules, but they all have this same issue.

Are there any ways, whether in Python or in another language, that I can simulate keypresses and type in the password on the login screen?

Comment: The Windows login screen is protect from overlaying, reading and writing by other applications. This is for security reasons. In your case it prevents a "fun" idea that is seen from the security perspective just horrible.

Comment: Shoot. Makes sense, this type of thing would be a security nightmare. Thanks for the response.